# python remove all header variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to remove all the headers from session after it is set? I want to use same session object to make HTTP request to different endpoints sequentially. Each of these endpoints require different sets of headers.

```
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers.update({"username": self.userid})
    session.headers.update({"password": self.password})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
session.headers = {}
```

which will reset it to an empty `dict`.

**EDIT**

Although I suppose the best way in case it's using some sort of internal type is something like

```
session.headers = type(session.headers)()
```

But if you want to make sure that anything else that references the headers are also emptied then

```
session.headers.clear()
```

is your best bet.

Comment: Presumably `session.headers.clear()` would also work, and avoid possible downsides of changing the type of `headers` (if `requests` uses some special internal mapping type normally; I have no idea if they do), or breaking expected aliasing (if `headers` is referenced from more than one place).